# Lookup Excel formula for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have this problem: get the threshold amount. please help
to get the threshold amount i need to follow the below matrix:

```
Tenor           Notional         Threshold
up to 1 yr      up to 500k         .05
up to 1 yr      500k to 1mio       .75
up to 1 yr      1mio above          .8
1-5yr           up to 500k         .1
1-5yr           500k to 1mio       .25
1-5yr           1mio above          .5
5-above          up to 500k         .3
5-above           500k to 1mio       .25
5-above           1mio above          .5
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to do :)?

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it this way, I have assumed you can add a helper column (in blue) where the Tenor and Notional values are concatenated together for the match to work.

Cells A2 and B2 have data validation lists so the target is chosen. The formulae is shown for both the result cell and the concatenation.

See: 
[image]